# How to update a profile picture across components which already has initials of the user using reactjs material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, avatar

I'm new to React. I have a homepage in my gatsby application with AppBar(Material UI ReactJs). I initially want to display user firstname and lastname initials. As I'm using msal-react to enable microsoft single-sign-on , I'm getting the intials from msal and updated the user avatar with AVatar in the homePage. I have a profile page, where I can upload a new picture and details. Its getting previewed on the Profile Page. But I would like to update the Avatar which is in home page too.

```
<Avatar {...stringAvatar(name)} />
function stringAvatar(name) {
   if(name !== null){
      const fullName = name.split(" ")[0] + " " + name.split(" ")[1];
      return {
         sx: {
             bgcolor: stringToColor(name),
         },
         children: `${fullName.split(' ')[0][0]}${fullName.split(' ')[1][0]}`,
      };
   }
   else{
       console.log("name is null");
   }

}
```

[image: HomePage]

This is my homepage
In the Profile Page, Initially I have put Avatar as like in the HomePage. I am able to upload the profile picture, name and designation in the profile and its getting reflected in the same page. But I have no idea how to make it preview in the homepage Navbar

[image: Avatar with initials]

[image: After uploading the image from my local]

[image: After clicking save]
The code which is in Profile Page

```
const ImgUpload = ({
onChange,
src
}) =>
<label htmlFor="photo-upload" className="custom-file-upload fas">
    <div className="img-wrap img-upload" >
        {src == 'https://github.com/OlgaKoplik/CodePen/blob/master/profile.jpg?raw=true' 
? <Avatar {...stringAvatar('Lakshmi Subramanian')} alt="LS" className="avatarCard" />
            : <img for="photo-upload" src={src} />}
    </div>
    <input id="photo-upload" type="file" onChange={onChange} />
</label>

export class CardProfile extends React.Component{


state = {
    file: '',
    imagePreviewUrl: 'https://github.com/OlgaKoplik/CodePen/blob/master/profile.jpg?raw=true',
    name: '',
    status: '',
    active: 'edit'
}

photoUpload = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const as = new AvatarSource();
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    as.setSrc(e.target.files[0].name);
    console.log(as.getSrc());      
    reader.onloadend = () => {
        this.setState({
            file: file,
            imagePreviewUrl: reader.result
        });
        as.setSrc(this.state.imagePreviewUrl);
        console.log("Inside Onloaded : " + as.getSrc());


    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}
editName = e => {
    const name = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
        name,
    });
}

editStatus = e => {
    const status = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
        status,
    });
}

handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let activeP = this.state.active === 'edit' ? 'profile' : 'edit';
    this.setState({
        active: activeP,
    })
}

render() {
    const { imagePreviewUrl,
        name,
        status,
        active } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            {(active === 'edit') ? (
                <Edit onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <ImgUpload onChange={this.photoUpload} src={imagePreviewUrl} />
                    <Name onChange={this.editName} value={name} />
                    <Status onChange={this.editStatus} value={status} />
                </Edit>
            ) : (
                <Profile
                    onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                    src={imagePreviewUrl}
                    name={name}
                    status={status} />)
            }
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Any help to update the profile pic after upload across the components will be highly appreciated!! TIA

Answer (score 0):

Your state must be a global state
Is your case:

```
state = {
    file: '',
    imagePreviewUrl: 'https://github.com/OlgaKoplik/CodePen/blob/master/profile.jpg?raw=true',
    name: '',
    status: '',
    active: 'edit'
}
```

You have different choise: Context, Recoil, Redux.
But as beginer a suggest Context as start, because its the official react team global state menagent system

Comment: I tried but nothing happens

Comment: can you share your code with as?